# Objects assigned to array don't want to start at index 1 when loaded with splice

Tags: javascript, arrays

I try to start an array index at 1 with

```
                    var entry = {};
                    entry['idSong'] = idSongVoted;
                    entry['voted'] = votedsong;
                    $scope.votedList.splice(idSongVoted, idSongVoted, entry);
```

but i have always starter at zero :

[image]

i need the index is same as the idSong

idSongVoted is a integer with values 1 to 12, without zero

Comment: JavaScript `Array`s are `0`-based. Attempting to start at `1` results in a [sparse array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array).

Comment: Since the `1` - `12` are "IDs" rather than necessarily indices, perhaps a plain [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) would be appropriate.

Comment: You should consider using an object as suggested by @Jonathan Lonowski, but you can also add an empty or null item at the 0th index and simply ignore it.

Comment: What a naughty Array!

Answer (score 1):

This problem is caused by the *incorrect* usage of [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). While JavaScript arrays are 0-based, neither this nor being a "sparse array" nor "not a normal object" are immediately relevant.

The `splice` function is simply *not* the correct tool for this task<sup>1</sup>.

```
var a = []
a.splice(1, 1, "a")
// a => ["a"]
a.splice(3, 3, "c")
// a => ["a", "c"]
a.splice(2, 2, "b")
// a => ["a", "c", "b"]
```

A trivial fix is to assign to each array index directly - if a "normal object" was used it would be considered assigning to each property directly.

```
var a = []
a[1] = "a"
a[3] = "c"
a[2] = "b"
// a => [undefined, "a", "b", "c"]
```

In context of the code the fix would simply be:

```
$scope.votedList[idSongVoted] = entry;
```

One *nice* thing about using a "sparse array" as shown - as *no* value was assigned to index 0 - is that `Arrays.forEach` *and* `angular.forEach` will correctly enumerate items in the numerical order of "id" *and* skip the indexes without values assigned. (If a value like null or undefined were assigned to the 0th index then the forEach loops would need guards added!)

However, if the "id" values are *not* relatively densely packed non-negative integers around 0 then a "normal object", which is supported by `angular.forEach`, would be a much better choice for an "id"-to-entry Map. This is for both logical/semantic and performance reasons.

---

<sup>1</sup> Per the [MDN Array.splice documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> Index at which to start changing the array. *If greater than the length of the array, actual starting index will be set to the length of the array.* If negative, will begin that many elements from the end.

This means `a.splice(1, 1, "a")`, when `a` is an empty array, is equivalent to `a.splice(0, 1, "a")`. This same issue also affects `a.splice(3, 3, "c")` when the array only has two elements - which leads to the overall incorrect ordering of `["a", "c", "b"]` when the "id" used is not strictly ordered.

Supplying the "id" to `howMany` is *also* problematic, although such is not shown in the example. Just don't use splice here.

Answer (score 1):

The javascript arrays usually start with the index `0`.You can start with the index as 1 with sparse array(object).

So here you need  is Javascript [objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)